# How do I insert my gridview group header values into my database?

Tags: asp.net

I have a gridview with group header. I need to insert the gridview values in to the database. Everything is inserted except the group header value. Can anyone please help me?  How can I insert the group header values in to the DB?

```
protected void Btn_Insert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{                      
    foreach (GridViewRow gvr in GridView3.Rows)   //loop through GridView
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("");
        if (gvr.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            string qry = "INSERT INTO [] ([ID],[ResourceType],[ResourceDetails],[Rota],[ChargeoutType],[Quantity], [Duration],[UOM], [ChargeRate]) VALUES ('" + test_id.Text.ToString() + "','" + gvr.Cells[1].Text + "','" + gvr.Cells[2].Text + "','" + gvr.Cells[3].Text + "','" + gvr.Cells[4].Text + "','" + gvr.Cells[5].Text + "','" + gvr.Cells[6].Text + "','" + gvr.Cells[7].Text + "','" + gvr.Cells[8].Text + "')";

            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(qry, con);
            con.Open();
            com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
        }
```

The `ResourceType` is the `GridView` row header.

```
GridViewHelper helper = new GridViewHelper(GridView3);

helper.RegisterGroup("ResourceType", true, true);
helper.ApplyGroupSort();
```